# Проблема с установкой балуна метки в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, vue.js, яндекс-карты

http://jsfiddle.net/z3pjcnLq/1/

На vue написан компонент (не суть важно), в который можно передавать координаты меток и они будут перерисовываться.

Проблема:
1. Загрузили страницу, кликнули на 'icon 4', имитируется загрузка с сервера, текст в balloon висит 'Загрузка...', хотя данные уже подгрузились. Закрываем его, открываем заново, данные на месте.

2.Клик 'icon 5', надписи 'Загрузка...' нет, данные подгрузились и не выводятся до тех пор, пока не закроем/откроем снова этот balloon

3. В кластере аналогично. Например, если после загрузки карты открыть кластер, и кликнуть по нескольким элементам списка, то видно, что текст 'Загрузка...' пишется только тогда, когда мы переключимся на другой элемент списка а потом снова на этот.

Проблема возникает здесь

```
setBalloon(obj) {
    if (this.loadingBalloon[obj.id]) return;
    this.loadingBalloon[obj.id] = true;
    if (!obj.properties.balloonContent) {
        obj.properties.balloonContent = 'Загрузка...'; // это ставится
        this.loadInfo(obj.id, (ok, data) => {
            if (ok) {
                obj.properties.balloonContent = data; // здесь содержимое balloon должно обновиться, в памяти оно обновляется
                console.log(obj.properties.balloonContent); // выводится
            } else {
                obj.properties.balloonContent = null;
            }
            this.loadingBalloon[obj.id] = false;
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что loadInfo возвращает `ok, data` а не `error, data` ? и что вам не надо вместо `if (ok) {` вставить `if (!error) {`

Comment: Уверен, проблему вы не там ищите.

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом (функция `ymapBalloonForceUpdate` вызывается после каждого изменения `properties.balloonContent`.

```
ymapBalloonForceUpdate(obj) {
        const objBalloon = this.ymapObjectManager.objects.balloon.getData();
        if (objBalloon) {
            if (obj.id === objBalloon.id) {
                // Форсировать отрисовку данных
                this.ymapObjectManager.objects.balloon.open(obj.id);
            }
        }

        const clusterBalloon = this.ymapObjectManager.clusters.balloon.getData();
        if (clusterBalloon) {
            const activeObject = this.ymapObjectManager.clusters.state.get('activeObject');
            if (activeObject && activeObject.id === obj.id) {
                const isOpen = this.ymapObjectManager.clusters.balloon.isOpen(clusterBalloon.id);
                if (isOpen) {
                    this.ymapObjectManager.clusters.balloon.open(clusterBalloon.id);
                }
            }
        }
    },

      setBalloon(obj) {
        if (this.loadingBalloon[obj.id]) return;
        this.loadingBalloon[obj.id] = true;
        if (!obj.properties.balloonContent) {
          obj.properties.balloonContent = 'Загрузка...';
          this.ymapBalloonForceUpdate(obj);
          this.loadInfo(obj.id, (ok, data) => {
            if (ok) {
              obj.properties.balloonContent = data;
              this.ymapBalloonForceUpdate(obj);
            }
            this.loadingBalloon[obj.id] = false;
          });
        }
      },
```