# Не отображается balloon у метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Делаю все по данному туториалу https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage

мой js

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
                zoom: 16,
                controls: ['smallMapDefaultSet']
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            }),


            myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
                balloonContentHeader: "Балун метки",
                balloonContentBody: "Содержимое <em>балуна</em> метки",
                balloonContentFooter: "Подвал",
                hintContent: "Хинт метки"
            }, {
                // Опции.
                // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
                iconLayout: 'default#image',
                // Своё изображение иконки метки.
                iconImageHref: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Littlebluedog.svg/150px-Littlebluedog.svg',
            });

        myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

        myMap.geoObjects
            .add(myPlacemark);
    });
```

```css
html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <div id="map"></div>
```

Метка просто не кликабельна. В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: в вашем коде выше метка кликабельна

Comment: Может тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674392/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85 есть решение?

Comment: Среди этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+balloon списка точно нет решения даной проблемы?

Comment: Заметил нечто подобное ...барабанная дробь... если на телфонах есть защитная пленка

Answer (score 1):

Собственно дело было в стилях

html,
body {height: 100%;font-size: 14px;min-width: 320px;position: relative;line-height: 1.75;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;, sans-serif;overflow-x: hidden;opacity: 1;background-color: #fff;color: #232323}

А если конкретно то в overflow-x - убрал данный кусок, всё заработало.